# Taking mean of N largest values of group by absolute value

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some DataFrame:

```
d = {'fruit': ['apple', 'pear', 'peach'] * 6, 'values': np.random.uniform(-5,5,18), 'values2': np.random.uniform(-5,5,18)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I can take the mean of each `fruit` group as such:

```
df.groupby('fruit').mean()
```

However, for each group of fruit, I'd like to take the mean of the N number of largest values as
ranked by absolute value.

So for example, if my values were as follows and N=3:

```
[ 0.7578507 ,  3.81178045, -4.04810913,  3.08887538,  2.87999752, 4.65670954]
```

The desired outcome would be (4.65670954 + -4.04810913 + 3.81178045) / 3 = **~1.47**

Edit - to clarify that sign is preserved in outcome:

(4.65670954 + -20.04810913 + 3.81178045) / 3 = **-3.859**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updating** with a new approach that I think is simpler.  I was avoiding `apply` like the plague but maybe this is [one of the more acceptable uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433552/13386979).  Plus it fixes the fact that you want to mean the original values *as ranked* by their absolute values:

```
def foo(d):
    return d[d.abs().nlargest(3).index].mean()
    
out = df.groupby('fruit')['values'].apply(foo)
```

So you index each group by the 3 largest absolute values, then mean.

*And for the record my original, incorrect, and slower code was:*

```
df['values'].abs().groupby(df['fruit']).nlargest(3).groupby("fruit").mean()
```

Comment: Is the sign preserved? E.g. with values such as: (4.65670954 + -20.04810913 + 3.81178045) / 3, desired outcome is **-3.859**

Comment: @BuffaloCollector Oh no I don't think so; so you want to select the values to mean based on their absolute value, but you want to average their original values?

Comment: That's right, like: `np.mean(sorted([4.65670954 + -20.04810913 + 3.81178045], key=abs, reverse=True)[:3])`

Comment: This seems to work but it may not be the most efficient: `np.mean(sorted(df.loc[df['fruit'] == 'apple']['values'].values, key=abs, reverse=True)[:3])`

Comment: Very nice! Didn't even consider `groupby.apply`. GroupBy objects are scary...